# What is the difference between a conservatory and an orangery?

Tags: new-home

I will shortly move into a new home in Abergavenny in Wales, which I have already asked my wife about extending. I am more curious at the moment, but the plan is to build the extension in the next year. I am looking at building either a [conservatory](http://www.firstchoicewindowsystems.co.uk/abergavenny-conservatories.html) or an [orangery](http://www.firstchoicewindowsystems.co.uk/orangeries-abergavenny.html) and can't really see the differences.

The company I linked to built my friend's conservatory last year and that is why I am using them as examples.

What is the difference between a conservatory and an orangery?

Comment: This is an open-ended question that probably can't be answered. It probably comes down to personal preference and budget.

Comment: @steven: the "better" part is subjective, true; but the core question about the differences is acceptible, I think.

Comment: Quick look at Wikipedia seems to imply for your purposes that they are the same.

Comment: Typically, and orangery is a brick structure with large glass windows/doors.  A conservatory is a glass structure -- more like a greenhouse, but may have a brick knee-wall as a foundation..

Answer (score 3):

From Google:

```
or·ange·ry  
/ˈôrənjrē/
Noun
A greenhouse where orange trees are grown.
Synonyms
hothouse
```

So, structurally speaking, there is no difference between the terms. The difference is merely based on what you put inside of it (whether or not you put orange trees in it). (If you grow lemon trees, is it a Lemony?)

Comment: Thanks but someone on another forum mentioned planning permission is different, so I am checking with albion. Have to agree, I dont see the difference but there is a price difference, and that has me wondering.